# Jquery-ui creates unspecified error when loading iFrame in IE9

Tags: jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-9

I'm loading the latest jQuery and jQuery-ui inside an iFrame in IE9.

I get an unspecified error regarding the `active = document.activeElement;`. If I delve into the jquery-ui code and return null:

```
active = null;
```

This solves my problem as it seems `document.activeElement` is not set in IE9 when initiated from within an iFrame.

I have also read similar issues elsewhere:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2064

I don't really want to edit jquery-ui with a try/catch but it is an option.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13378

Best solution is to place following script **within the iFrame** HTML

```
/* Bug Fix: IE9 >>> http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13378 */
jQuery(function () { document.documentElement.focus(); });
```

Comment: This works well for me in IE9 but throws a script error for me in IE8 if my iframe is not yet visible when it's loaded.

Comment: I have no IE8 anymore, so I can't test it with it, though my suggestion would be to call the function onLoad of the iFrame then.

Comment: Unfortunately, my solution involves adding HTML into the frame that I'm not really in a position to start injecting this script into... Definitely not an easy solution for my context... I'm now wondering what's the best solution in editing jquery.ui itself, using active = null as specified in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I belive the problem is IE9 loading the "src" of the iframe before it is attached to the DOM, and then jQuery does not have a "document".